# crossrider binding to DOM events

Tags: jquery, events, crossrider

I have just started out looking at crossrider to develop a browser extension.  I am impressed with the concept, but it could do with a little more help in the odcumentation and examples.

My specific problem is that I want the extension.js file to be able to recognise and work with specific DOM events on the loaded page i.e. the onblur event

In a normal inline javascript, I would use
    $(":input").on("blur", function(e){
        // do stuff
    });

but I am completely lost as to how/where I would place this code in the exension.js file.  I have tried both within and outside of the appAPI.ready function, but neiher of these seems to trigger anything on the loaded page

I know I could forcibly include a remote JS file containing my code, but that would mean I would lose access to the appAPI functions and I would have to use the messaging API to pass information between the web page and the extension.  This approach seems messy

Where am I going wrong in trying to use get the extension to bind to the onblur event on the web page?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's as easy as adding the jQuery code within the [appAPI.ready](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI-method-ready) method's callback function in the *extension.js* file, as you mentioned. I tested your example using the following code on Win7/Chrome:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  $(":input").on("blur", function(e){ console.log(':input blur'); });
});
```

If this isn't working for you, I recommend opening a Crossrider support ticket (support@crossrider.com) specifying the extension id and we will be happy to investigate for you.

[image: jQuery example]

Disclaimer: I am a Crossrider employee.

Comment: Thanks for the response - I will copy your code into my extension to test it and see if I can build up the actions piece by piece from the bottom up.  I already have working Javascript for the actions I want to take, so I should be able to sort it with a lot of console.log help

Comment: The code that you supplied worked fine and I was able to build upon it to acheive my desired results by gradually copying and pasting  snippets of my existing code.  Thanks again